# VS Code Apex Language Server Error

Tags: vs-code

I am experiencing an issue with the Apex Language Server not running in VS Code. I have looked for solutions to this issue. The only thing I found recommended trying to set the Java path in the Salesforce VS Code extension settings. That was already set. Everything has been working for a long time until just recently. I updated the extension pack as well but that didn't help.

I'm not sure where else to look.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem. Apex Language Server in VSCode failed to launch because it is now compiled requiring a later version of Java. Check the Apex Language Server panel to confirm the errors.

My error was: ApexLanguageServerLauncher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235517/unsupportedclassversionerror-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the), class file 55.0 means I would need to have Java 11 and I only had Java 8 on my Mac.

Solution:

Go to Adoptium.net as recommended [here](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/a-guide-to-java-versions-and-features) and download the JDK. I got MacOs x64 JDK 17 Temurin which is the latest LTS version. Download it, check the checksum and install it.

In VSCode:

```
Preferences > Search for java, then set
Salesforcedx-vscode-apex › Java: Home
to:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Comment: Yeah, I discovered the same thing. I forgot to come back and update my question with an answer. It used to work for me so I guess the Salesforce extension updated to use a new version of Java.